# "Keycloak - Verify Email Issue"

Tags: keycloak

I am working with the **JHipster** built Application where we authenticate via **Keycloak(version 4.4.0 final).** 
During verify email, I am receiving an email with a confirmation link to confirm email. In a few situations, the verification link is not working. Below I have mentioned the steps that I did and problems.

**Steps:**

1. Registration with chrome
2. Get mail for email verification
3. Close the chrome and restart
4. Try to use verification link

**Problem:**
1. If I closed the current browser window/ open link in private window/ open link in a different browser, the link is not working anymore.

**Cause of the problem:**
This problem is accrued because of the cookies that **keycloak** creating during registration. `AUTH_SESSION_ID and KC_RESTART`
Because when I close the browser window these cookies are no more in a browser.

If I try to use a verification link is the same browser window that I used for Registration than it’s working fine. Because in this browser window those two Cookies are stored.

Answer (score -1):

With keycloak version 6.0.1,
they generating email verification link which supports to confirm from different browser...

- this link is helpful to verify the email from a different browser and incognito window too.

cheers

Comment: How can I find the link? Can you please be a bit more specific in this answer?

Comment: @alexander Verification link is automatically generated by Keyclaok. with version 6.0.1, verification link is supported to confirm from any browser